# "Staring down defeat" vs "Staring down the barrel of defeat"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, differences

Yesterday I asked a [question][1] about the meaning of "to stare down defeat" and I got an answer. But as I searched the net, I noticed that there's this phrase "to stare down the barrel of defeat" as a variant of "to stare down the barrel of gun". I wonder if, as one of the users mentioned in his comment on my previous question, "to stare down defeat" derives from "to stare down the barrel of gun/defeat".

As I learned from the previous question and from several examples on the net, "staring down defeat" means "struggling with and overcoming defeat personified as an opponent". But according to [usingenglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/stare+down+the++barrel+of+a+gun.html#:%7E:text=If%20someone%20is%20staring%20down,of%20something%20very%20bad%20happening.), "If someone is staring down the barrel of a gun, there's a high risk of something very bad happening". Examples:

"Murray stared down defeat just as fiercely as he glowered at a heckler in the crowd."

"Nick Nurse hailed the mental strength of his title-chasing Brighton Bears after they twice stared down the barrel of defeat and survived for a weekend win double."

Comment: Any reason for vote down?

Comment: I don't know, but as you will see from my comment below, I doubt that there is any connection between *to stare [someone/something] down* and *to stare down the barrel of a gun*: as you say, the meanings are different. The earliest use of "to stare down" in the OED is *1798   A. Browne Misc. Sketches I. 181   They are able with unblushing cheek to stare down the passenger who gazes at their beauty.* Also, in the former, "down" appears to be an adverb, and in the latter, a preposition.

Comment: What do they keep in _the barrel of defeat_? Rotten pickles?

Comment: @Greybeard - Your explanation seems logical, but what confused me about the phrase was the example I cited in my previous question: "Staring down defeat, Trump attempts a coronavirus reset." I thought the meaning of the phrase "to stare down the barrel of defeat" could apply to this example. Since Trump feared an imminent defeat [in the elections], he attempted a Coronavirus reset.

Comment: @TBY90 There is not a phrase *"to stare down the barrel of defeat."* (**Defeat** does not have a barrel): you can **1** *stare someone/something down*; **2** *be staring down the barrel of a gun* or **3** *stare something in the face.*

Answer (score -1):

I do not think those phrases are related at all, neither in etymology nor in meaning.

Grammatically, those two phrases use entirely different predicates - in "to stare down defeat", the predicate is the transitive "stare down", while in "to stare down the barrel of a gun", the predicate is the ambitransitive "stare". In other words, the latter phrase does not use "stare down" as a phrasal verb.

This difference, I think, carries over to the meaning - "to stare down defeat" implies a certain degree of haughtiness and defiance that staring someone or something down would, but "to stare down the barrel of a gun" doesn't - it means you're in peril, but it doesn't mean that you're facing this peril calmly and in a calculated way.

They're two separate idioms, and "to stare down the barrel of defeat" seems to be a relatively new (and interestingly UK/Australia-specific based on a quick Google search) combination of them.

Comment: You're probably correct, but your "answer" is in fact, a comment/opinion. You could firm it up by providing authoritative references.